# How to reduce pivot size and get only the required data using view?

Tags: sql-server, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have created a pivot excel file with filters in SQL views connected to the excel, its fine but the data in the pivot excel is too large to send in email (or) it has more unneccarsy data.

I need only the filtered data from the pivot excel file, so I tried copy and past special (only values) option to another excel file for getting the data. This reduced the size in a huge manner but the connection is lost so it's just an ordinary excel file.

The client doesn't need a parameterized stored procedure to reduce the size fo the file.

Is there any way to reduce the pivot excel file size with the exsisting connections ?

Thanks

Comment: Try saving the file as `Excel Binary Workbook (*.xlsb)`

Comment: No it didn't work...